# Adding code to angular-seed

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to web programming in general, and need to learn Angularjs. So I've gone through the tutorial on their site. I'm not very comfortable yet, but still I get to grips with mostly everything explained.

So after a quick look a the tutorial, I wanted a base to start doing something of my own from scratch. Came across angular-seed:
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

The problem is it's not really the same structure as the tutorial, and when I try and code, say for example to the controller of view one, like this (most recent attempt), it doesn't show the hello.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "hello";
}]);
```

and in the HTML, tried loads of different ways to access "test". None of them worked.

So my question is, what do I have to do to get test printed on my HTML page ?

I know this is probably the worst question ever asked on Stackoverflow, but I want to start programming with this angular-seed structure, and maybe better understand stuff latter.

Thanks

Comment: Well, did you run `bower install`?

Comment: npm install and npm start for the server. I followed the readme.

Comment: Tssss. Previous answer or worth than the question. Are you using a local server? First thing is to access your page. Inside your page, what's the application name's? Are you using the same name in your JS file? You do not forget to declare the ng-controller usage in your markup? The easiest way we can help you is to produce a jsfiddle (a google research will help you).

Comment: I cloned the got, npm install & npm start, tried the address in the readme.md file, it showed the page, but not my "test" variable. Any other code is left untouched, apart from the controller and html (with the minor modifications described above)

Answer (score 2):

try putting

```
{{test}}
```

inside `view1.html`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue and find that the issue came from the different controller names in the following .config and .controller.  The name should be the same, such as "View1Ctrl" or "view1ctrl".

```js
"use strict";

angular
  .module("myApp.view1", ["ngRoute"])

  .config([
    "$routeProvider",
    function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when("/view1", {
        templateUrl: "view1/view1.html",
        controller: "View1Ctrl",
      });
    },
  ])
  .controller("View1Ctrl", [
    "$scope",
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.test = "test";
  
    },
  ]);
```